# Link a dynamic named range that contains non-adjacent columns of a bigger table, from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, hyperlink, cpu-word

I have a large table with 20 columns in Excel, out of which I just need 4 columns to display in Word Document dynamically.

However, only data in the first cell of the range (that contains 4 columns and 30 rows) gets displayed in the Word document.

I have gone through different forums for a solution, but couldn't find one. Any solution / workaround shall be highly appreciated. Thanks.

I first went to the Excel, created a Named Range, named as 'InitTechStatus' with the below formula.

=INDEX(Tbl_AllDetails[#All],SEQUENCE(ROWS(Tbl_AllDetails[#All])),{1,2,4,8})

I am able to use the range 'InitTechStatus' elsewhere in Excel. However, I am unable to link to this range in Word Document.

I used the following in Word Document to link to the Excel

{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "E:\ProjData\ProjStatus.xlsx" "Sheet2!InitTechStatus" \a \f 5 \h  * MERGEFORMAT }

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround to achieve my objective. I went to an unused part of the worksheet, say, Cell 'AC23'. I typed the formula I require in the cell AC23. In my case, it is `=INDEX(Tbl_AllDetails[#All],SEQUENCE(ROWS(Tbl_AllDetails[#All])),{1,2,4,8})`. The data spills into the adjacent rows and columns.

Then I went to the Named Ranges and under the name, `InitTechStatus` I gave the formula `=Sheet1!$AC$23#`. The # denotes to excel that the spilled data from that cell is also included.

I later on used the following in Word Document to link to the specific Excel data that I require.

{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "E:\ProjData\ProjStatus.xlsx" "Sheet2!InitTechStatus" \a \f 5 \h * MERGEFORMAT }

The switches in the Link in the Word Document can also be changed as required.
[Excel to Word: Manipulating Field Codes and switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067150/excel-to-word-manipulating-field-codes-and-switches)